# Google sheets API, color of font, updating multiple ranges at once

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I currently update multiple ranges through looping through the ranges. Now I'm trying to update all of the ranges with one call. But I can't figure out where to put the second range. I think it is possible. I don't know. Here is my code.

```
from multicore import g

key = '1-I9CugmHB1Ds6n1jBy4Zo4hk_k4sQsTmOFfccxRc2qo'
robo_font_color = [0.6, 0.0, 0.3]


range1 = {'sheetId': 184514576, 'startRowIndex': 2, 'endRowIndex': 3, 'startColumnIndex': 6, 'endColumnIndex': 9}
range2 = {'sheetId': 184514576, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 3, 'startColumnIndex': 1, 'endColumnIndex': 2}


def font_color(key, color):  # color is a 1x3 list
    data = {"requests": [{
        "repeatCell": {
            "range": range1,
            
            
            "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                        "foregroundColor": {  # color of text
                            "red": color[0],
                            "green": color[1],
                            "blue": color[2]
                        },
                    }
                }
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.foregroundColor"
        }
        
    }]
    }
    g.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=key, body=data).execute()


    
font_color(key,robo_font_color)
```

Where do I put in `range2` so to update both ranges with one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

In your case, how about creating the requests using `[range1, range2]`?

#### Modified script:

```
from multicore import g

key = '1-I9CugmHB1Ds6n1jBy4Zo4hk_k4sQsTmOFfccxRc2qo'
robo_font_color = [0.6, 0.0, 0.3]

range1 = {'sheetId': 184514576, 'startRowIndex': 2, 'endRowIndex': 3, 'startColumnIndex': 6, 'endColumnIndex': 9}
range2 = {'sheetId': 184514576, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'endRowIndex': 3, 'startColumnIndex': 1, 'endColumnIndex': 2}

def font_color(key, color, ranges):  # color is a 1x3 list
    data = {"requests": [{
        "repeatCell": {
            "range": r,
            "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                        "foregroundColor": {  # color of text
                            "red": color[0],
                            "green": color[1],
                            "blue": color[2]
                        },
                    }
                }
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.foregroundColor"
        }
    } for r in ranges]}
    g.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=key, body=data).execute()


font_color(key,robo_font_color, [range1, range2])
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)