# How to update forecolor only in Google Sheets for specific cells

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I need to change the text colour of some cells while preserving the rest of the formatting using  Sheets API v4.
I followed a sample to the ForeColor for a cell range in [how-to-read/write-google-sheets-with-c#](https://www.hardworkingnerd.com/how-to-read-and-write-to-google-sheets-with-c).

```
        if (foreColor != System.Drawing.Color.Empty)
        {
            var spreadsheet = await service.Spreadsheets.Get(_spreadsheetId).ExecuteAsync();
            var sheet = spreadsheet.Sheets.First(s => s.Properties.Title == worksheetTitle);
            int sheetId = sheet.Properties.SheetId ?? 0;

            var cellFormat = new CellFormat
            {
                TextFormat = new TextFormat
                {
                    ForegroundColor = new Color
                    {
                        Alpha = foreColor.A / 255f,
                        Red = foreColor.R / 255f,
                        Green = foreColor.G / 255f,
                        Blue = foreColor.B / 255f,
                    }
                }
            };

            CellData getFormatted() => new CellData { UserEnteredFormat = cellFormat };

            var request = new Request
            {
                UpdateCells = new UpdateCellsRequest
                {
                    Start = new GridCoordinate
                    {
                        SheetId = _sheetId,
                        ColumnIndex = startColumnIndex,
                        RowIndex = rowNumber - 1,
                    },
                    Fields = "*",
                    Rows = new List<RowData> { new RowData { 
                        Values = new List<CellData>
                        {
                            getFormatted(), //  details
                            getFormatted(), //  system type
                            getFormatted(), //  price
                            getFormatted(), //  primary cost
                            getFormatted(), //  secondary cost
                            getFormatted(), //  accepted
                        }
                    } },
                },
            };

            var requests = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest
            {
                ResponseIncludeGridData = true,
                Requests = new List<Request> { request },
            };

            var response = await service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(requests, spreadsheet.SpreadsheetId).ExecuteAsync();
        }
```

The problem with the code above is that while it does change the text colour, it also clears all cell values and existing formatting - (like borders, text-align, etc.).

Is there a way to only update cell text colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at it, `Fields = "*",` will replace all fields. Since you only wish to update `foregroundColor`, try using this instead:

```
Fields = "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.foregroundColor"
```

#### Sample request body:

```
"requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        // A:B
        "range": {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 2
        },
        // change font color to blue
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredFormat": {
            "textFormat": {
              "foregroundColor": {
                "blue": 1
              }
              // included bold for fields demonstration
              "bold": true
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.foregroundColor"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Notice that I included bold below the `foregroundColor`. Since we just specified `userEnteredFormat.textFormat.foregroundColor` in the fields, it will just update that `foregroundColor` in the request (neglecting the bold)

Issue on yours is that, you used `*`, thus replacing all formats and values, removing the cell values and formats entirely since you don't have values for the other fields in your request.

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Sample references you can check:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42926565/14606045
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66981838/14606045
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63442303/14606045

Comment: Perfect! Huge thank you - worked like a charm :-)